# zsh: Command not found (for $EDITOR)

Tags: macos, terminal, zsh, gnu-screen, zshrc

For whatever reason, zsh doesn't like me setting command-line arguments for my `$EDITOR` variable, but from what I can tell, it's not supposed to be this way. I've seen people use

```
export EDITOR='open -Wn'
```

in their ~/.zshrc file, but when I try to do that, I just get a complaint.

```
zsh: command not found: open -Wn
```

Any reason why this might be happening? Setting the `$EDITOR` to `'mate'`, `'vim'` or `'open'` seems to work just fine, but `'mate -w'` and `'open -Wn'` don't work.

I'm running zsh inside screen on Mac OS X, and my ~/.zshrc is as follows:

```
# -----------------------------------------------
# Screen Settings
# -----------------------------------------------

# If screen isn't already running, turn it on.
if [[ $STY == '' ]]; then
    # Execute screen.
    exec screen -aADRU
fi

# -----------------------------------------------
# Startup Scripts
# -----------------------------------------------

cd ~/Desktop
[[ -s "~/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "~/.rvm/scripts/rvm"

# -----------------------------------------------
# Environment Variables
# -----------------------------------------------

export HISTFILE=~/.zsh_history
export HISTSIZE=10000
export HISTCONTROL=ignoredups
export SAVEHIST=10000

export PATH=.:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/narwhal/bin:/bin:/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/share:/usr/sbin:/usr/local/texlive/2011/bin/universal-darwin
export EDITOR='open -Wn'
export LC_TYPE=en_US.UTF-8
export LSCOLORS=exFxcxdxAxexbxHxGxcxBx

# -----------------------------------------------
# Prompt
# -----------------------------------------------

## Root Prompt
[ $UID = 0 ] && export PROMPT="%~ +=> " && export RPROMPT="%*"

## General Prompt
[ $UID != 0 ] && export PROMPT="%~ => " && export RPROMPT="%*"

# -----------------------------------------------
# Aliases
# -----------------------------------------------

## Command Aliases
alias ..='cd ..'
alias ...='cd ../..'
alias internet='lsof -P -i -n | cut -f 1 -d " " | uniq'
alias restart='sudo shutdown -r NOW'
alias ls='ls -@1AFGph'
alias tree='tree -alCF --charset=UTF-8 --du --si'
alias mate='mate -w'
alias zshrc='$EDITOR ~/.zshrc && source ~/.zshrc'
alias vimrc='$EDITOR ~/.vimrc.local'
alias gvimrc='$EDITOR ~/.gvimrc.local'

## Root Aliases
[ $UID = 0 ] && \
    alias rm='rm -i' && \
    alias mv='mv -i' && \
    alias cp='cp -i'

# -----------------------------------------------
# User-defined Functions
# -----------------------------------------------

# Usage: extract <file>
# Description: extracts archived files / mounts disk images.
# Note: .dmg/hdiutil is Mac OS X-specific.
extract () {
    if [ -f $1 ]; then
        case $1 in
            *.tar.bz2)  tar -jxvf $1        ;;
            *.tar.gz)   tar -zxvf $1        ;;
            *.bz2)      bunzip2 $1          ;;
            *.dmg)      hdiutul mount $1    ;;
            *.gz)       gunzip $1           ;;
            *.tar)      tar -xvf $1         ;;
            *.tbz2)     tar -jxvf $1        ;;
            *.tgz)      tar -zxvf $1        ;;
            *.zip)      unzip $1            ;;
            *.Z)        uncompress $1       ;;
            *)          echo "'$1' cannot be extracted/mounted via extract()." ;;
        esac
    else
        echo "'$1' is not a valid file."
    fi
}


# Usage: pman <manpage>
# Description: opens up the selected man page in Preview.
pman () {
    man -t $@ | open -f -a /Applications/Preview.app
}

# Usage: fp <name>
# Description: find and list processes matching a case-insensitive partial-match string.
fp () {
    ps Ao pid,comm|awk '{match($0,/[^\/]+$/); print substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)": "$1}'|grep -i $1|grep -v grep
}

# Usage: fk <name>
# Description: find and kill a process matching a case-insensitive partial-match string.
fk () {
    IFS=$'\n'
    PS3='Kill which process? (1 to cancel): '
    select OPT in "Cancel" $(fp $1); do
        if [ $OPT != "Cancel" ]; then
            kill $(echo $OPT|awk '{print $NF}')
        fi
        break
    done
    unset IFS
}

# Usage: create <file>
# Description: creates and opens a file for editing.
create () {
    touch $1 && open $1
}

# Usage: reset
# Description: 'resets' the terminal by changing the current working directory
# to the desktop and clearing the screen.
reset () {
    cd ~/Desktop; clear
}

# Usage: quit
# Description: exits the terminal.
quit () {
    killall Terminal
}

# -----------------------------------------------
# zsh Options
# -----------------------------------------------

# Directories
setopt                  \
    AUTO_CD             \
    AUTO_PUSHD          \
    CD_ABLE_VARS        \
    CHASE_DOTS          \
    CHASE_LINKS         \

# Completion
setopt                  \
    AUTO_LIST           \
    AUTO_MENU           \
    AUTO_PARAM_SLASH    \
    COMPLETE_IN_WORD    \
    LIST_TYPES          \
    MENU_COMPLETE       \
    REC_EXACT           \

# History
setopt                  \
    APPEND_HISTORY      \
    EXTENDED_HISTORY    \

# Input/Output
setopt                  \
    CORRECT             \

# Scripts and Functions
setopt                  \
    MULTIOS             \

# Other
setopt                  \
    NO_BEEP             \
    ZLE

# Key Bindings
bindkey "^[[3~" delete-char

# -----------------------------------------------
# zsh Autocompletion
# -----------------------------------------------

# Turn on auto-completion.
autoload -U compinit && compinit -C && autoload -U zstyle+

# Attempt to complete as much as possible.
zstyle ':completion:*' completer _complete _list _oldlist _expand _ignored _match _correct
zstyle ':completion:*::::' completer _expand _complete _ignored _approximate

# Sort files by name.
zstyle ':completion:*' file-sort name

# Allow for case-insensitive completion.
zstyle ':completion:*' matcher-list 'm:{a-zA-Z}={A-Za-z}'

# Color completions.
zstyle ':completion:*' list-colors ${LSCOLORS}
zstyle ':completion:*:*:kill:*:processes' command 'ps -axco pid,user,command'
zstyle ':completion:*:*:kill:*:processes' list-colors '=(#b) #([0-9]#)*=0=01;31'

# Set the amount of completions that triggers the menu.
zstyle ':completion:*' menu select=long

# Ignore certain patterns.
zstyle ':completion:*:functions' ignored-patterns '_*'
zstyle ':completion:*:complete:-command-::commands' ignored-patterns '*\~'
zstyle ':completion:*:*:(^rm):*:*files' ignored-patterns '*?.(o|c~|old|pro|zwc)'

# Cache completions.
zstyle ':completion::complete:*' use-cache 1
zstyle ':completion::complete:*' cache-path ~/.zcompcache/$HOST

# Allow errors.
zstyle -e ':completion:*:approximate:*' max-errors 'reply=( $(( ($#PREFIX+$#SUFFIX)/2 )) numeric )'

# Insert all expansions for expand completer (eh, don't know what this does).
zstyle ':completion:*:expand:*' tag-order all-expansions

# Formatting and messages.
zstyle ':completion:*' list-prompt '%SAt %p: Hit TAB for more, or the character to insert%s'
zstyle ':completion:*' verbose yes
zstyle ':completion:*:descriptions' format '%B%d%b'
zstyle ':completion:*:messages' format '%d'
zstyle ':completion:*:warnings' format 'No matches for: %d'
zstyle ':completion:*:corrections' format '%B%d (errors: %e)%b'
zstyle ':completion:*' group-name ''

# Offer indexes before parameters in subscripts.
zstyle ':completion:*:*:-subscript-:*' tag-order indexes parameters
```

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: @jww This is a 6.5-year-old question with an accepted answer. Was this really necessary?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In zsh, when you write `$EDITOR`, it expands to a single word. Unlike other Bourne-style shells, zsh does not split words when it expands unquoted expansions. You can make it happen with the
[`=` modifier on parameter expansion](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#index-SH_005fWORD_005fSPLIT_002c-toggle).

```
$=EDITOR $file
```

A more portable method is to ensure that `EDITOR` does not contain any space. Most applications treat `$EDITOR` as a shell snippet or as a whitespace-separated list of words, but I've encountered a few that treat it as a command name. Make `EDITOR` point to a shell script.

```
% cat ~/bin/EDITOR
#!/bin/sh
open -Wn -- "$@"
% grep EDITOR ~/.profile
export EDITOR=~/bin/EDITOR
```

Comment: Thanks! Just ran in to this trying to set `EDITOR=emacsclient -c` in zsh; I had no idea about this difference between zsh and Bash.

Answer (score 3):

How are you invoking the EDITOR?  If you have EDITOR set with options, then you would get an error with:

```
$ $EDITOR file
```

but it should work if you do:

```
$ eval $EDITOR file
```

Comment: Rather than call `eval`, you can turn on word splitting specifically on this expansion: `$=EDITOR file`.

Comment: Wow, didn't know that was possible. Great tip!

Comment: @Gilles: is there a reason you didn't put that in as an answer?  It seems to be the best answer to me, and I'd gladly up-vote it.  I'm tempted to put it in myself as an answer, but if I told people to up-vote your comment instead, the answer wouldn't be seen easily, as it would fall to the bottom.  And if people just up-voted my answer, I'd feel like I was stealing points that rightfully are yours.

Comment: @iconoclast I suppose I felt that William's answer was close enough. Oh well, I've posted an answer now.

Answer (score 1):

Programs that invoke the editor defined by `$EDITOR` may assume that the whole string referenced by it is the name of the command.  So they will try to find an executable file called `open -Wn`.

Another issue is that open merely opens the file with an application that the operating system deems appropriate.  If there is no application associated with the file type, the command will fail.

Comment: Alright, that makes sense, but why would this work for other people, but not me?

Comment: @Itai:  I don't know.  Frankly, I'm amazed that other people have got it to work.

Comment: Simply setting EDITOR="open -Wn" will work in bash, since word splitting is on by default.  Perhaps the "other people" are not using zsh?

Comment: That's most likely it. Thanks, William.